# How to install software on a remote server from local disk

Tags: windows, installation, remote-desktop

I have a brand new Amazon EC2 instance.  This instance is a Windows Server.

I have SQL Server on DVD that I want to install on the remote server.

The problem is the message I get when attempting to install stating that Windows Install does not allow installation from and RDP session.

Please advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always make an ISO of your DVD, upload it to your server and then create a Virtual CD drive to mount the ISO. This would probably be the easiest way.

Comment: Would a simple copy/paste work.  Is an ISO conversion necessary?

Comment: @AndroidAddict Converting to an ISO will allow you to verify the file is complete.

Comment: This would be the preferred method. You could also simply copy the contents of the DVD into a desktop folder on the target machine and run setup from within that. I prefer this method on machines I don't feel like mucking up with CD emulation software.

Comment: A copy and paste could work. However, I like to always do a MD5 Checksum to make sure that my files are not corrupted once they make it over to the target computer.

Comment: I did the simple copy/paste and it worked fine.